# Synchronously iterate through firestore collection

Tags: node.js, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a firebase callable function that does some batch processing on documents in a collection.

The steps are

1. Copy document to a separate collection, archive it
2. Run http request to third party service based on data in document
3. If 2 was successful, delete document

I'm having trouble with forcing the code to run synchronously. I can't figure out the correct await syntax.

```
async function archiveOrders  (myCollection: string) {

//get documents in array for iterating
const currentOrders = [];
console.log('getting current orders');
await db.collection(myCollection).get().then(querySnapshot => {
    querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
        currentOrders.push(doc.data());
    });
});

console.log(currentOrders);

//copy Orders
currentOrders.forEach (async (doc) => {

    if (something about doc data is true ) {
        let id = "";
        id = doc.id.toString();
        await db.collection(myCollection).doc(id).set(doc);
        console.log('this was copied: ' + id, doc);
    }

});
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve the problem I made a separate function call which returns a promise that I can await for.
I also leveraged the QuerySnapshot which returns an array of all the documents in this QuerySnapshot. See [here](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/QuerySnapshot.html) for usage.

```
// from inside cloud function
// using firebase node.js admin sdk

const current_orders = await db.collection("currentOrders").get();

for (let index = 0; index < current_orders.docs.length; index++) {
  const order = current_orders.docs[index];
  await archive(order);
}


async function archive(doc) {

    let docData = await doc.data();

if (conditional logic....) {
    try {
      // await make third party api request
      await db.collection("currentOrders").doc(id).delete();

    }
    catch (err) {
      console.log(err)
    }
} //end if

} //end archive
```

Answer (score 0):

Now i'm not familiar with firebase so you will have to tell me if there is something wrong with how i access the data.

You can use `await` [Promise.all()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) to wait for all promises to resolve before you continue the execution of the function, `Promise.all()` will fire all requests simultaneously and will not wait for one to finish before firing the next one.

Also although the syntax of `async/await` looks synchronous, things still happen asynchronously

```
async function archiveOrders(myCollection: string) {
  console.log('getting current orders')
  const querySnapshot = await db.collection(myCollection).get()
  const currentOrders = querySnapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data())

  console.log(currentOrders)

  await Promise.all(currentOrders.map((doc) => {
    if (something something) {
      return db.collection(myCollection).doc(doc.id.toString()).set(doc)
    }
  }))

  console.log('copied orders')
}
```